# Publish Azure Devops Artifacts to Maven Central

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

Can any one suggest a flow how to publish Azure Devops server 2019 maven artifacts (exposes API) to Maven central for a more global access?

update:

let me rephrase my issue.
my team uses on-premise Azure Devops to develop and host android packages used as API for other applications.
when the API version is stable we want to publish the API packages (in the on-premise artifacts) to Maven central, i wish to use the release management so i could use the approve mechanism

Comment: Hi Liran, stackoverflow is not for suggesting tutorials but for solving specific problems. Googling for a tutorial or a dedicated forum will probably help you more.

Comment: I know it's not meant for tutorials, I am looking for suggestion to a specific problem

Answer (score 0):

Azure Artifacts, part of Azure DevOps, offers the ability to host and share Maven, npm, NuGet, and Python package feeds within your organization.

If you want to host the packages on Maven central instead of Azure Artifacts. You would check how to upload packages to Maven central on Maven side:

https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html

If your goal is only sharing packages publicly, you may try Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com), which support [sharing your packages publicly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/share-packages-publicly?view=azure-devops). This feature currently only support Azure DevOps Service.

Comment: please note that I'm using the On-premise version of Azure Devops.
the API packages are developed in the the organization and when it becomes stable they will to publish it to Maven Central

Comment: If you mean you want to publish artifacts to Maven Central from Azure Pipeline, you need to check how to upload packages to Maven central on Maven side: https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html, meet the requirements and publish the artifacts from commands. Here is a public blog you may refer to: https://dzone.com/articles/publish-your-artifacts-to-maven-central.